# В чем разница между docker image ls , docker images ls и docker images?

Tags: docker

В чем разница между `docker image ls`, `docker images ls` и `docker images`?

Comment: команда `docker image ls` эквивалентна `docker images`. Документация на `image ls` прямо ссылается на `images`: [**Description** See docker images for more information](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_ls/)

Answer (score 1):

Что `docker image ls` и `docker images`, выводят в консоль список образов их тэги, id, время создания и размер.
Про такую команду, как `docker images ls` не слышал.

А вообще у Docker очень хорошая [документация](https://docs.docker.com/)

Comment: Значит `docker image ls` и `docker images` это одно и тоже?

Comment: Да, результат получается одинаковый.

Answer (score 1):

Команда `docker image ls` эквивалентна `docker images`.

[Исходный код для `image ls`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli/command/image/list.go#L58):

```go
func newListCommand(dockerCli command.Cli) *cobra.Command {
    cmd := *NewImagesCommand(dockerCli)
    cmd.Aliases = []string{"list"}
    cmd.Use = "ls [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]"
    return &cmd
}
```

То есть команда `image ls` получается из `images` заменой синтаксиса `images [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]` -> `ls [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]` (поле `Use`) и добавлением синонима `image list` (поле `Aliases`).

В команде `images` [поле `Annotations`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/bc6b9d9c4b835fd1d6741af661039f53a17a6ae8/cli/command/image/list.go#L42C4-L42C71) прямо сообщает:

```go
        Annotations: map[string]string{
            "category-top": "7",
            "aliases":      "docker image ls, docker image list, docker images",
        },
```

Команды `docker image ls`, `docker image list`, `docker images` эквивалентны.

Comment: Не очень понятно потому что я не знаю go, но спасибо информацию